# Cyclic dependency between static class and instance produced by static class

Tags: php

I making my code in PHP and have two classes: Producer and Member. Producer is static class which produces and caches Member instances. Member can work with another Member instance but in order to obtain it it needs to call Producer to get it.

```
class Producer
  {
    static private $members = array();

    static function getMember($name)
      {
         if (!isset(self::$members[$name]))
           {
             self::$members[$name] = new Member($name);
           }
         return self::$members[$name];
      }

    static function getFriend($myname, $friendname)
      {
         // Disregard $myname at the moment as irrelevant
         return self::$members[$friendname];
      }
  }

class Member
  {
    private $myname;

    public function __construct($name)
      {
         $this->myname = $name;
      }

    public function getFriend($name)
      {
         return Producer::getFriend($this->myname, $name);
      }

    public function work()
      {
        $friend = $this->getFriend($name);
        $friend->doSomething();
      }
  }
```

Clearly this is cyclic dependency and needs to be eliminated. It would be good to use dependency injection in this case and just pass instance of Producer to a Member on instantiation but Producer is static class.

What is the best way to handle such issue? Introduce singleton MembersCache and pass it to each member? Seems clunky to me

Comment: It appears that all `Producer` does is just act as a `MemberCollection` type. Rather than making `Producer` a class that just contains a static member array of `Member` types, with static methods, why not just have a `MemberCollection` type instead? Or at the very least (as you point out) just inject the `Member` into `Producer::getMember()`? The question seems counter-intuitive. It's like you're asking "*how can I do this and not do this at the same time*"... but clearly you already know the answer; **just don't do that**.

Comment: this is not circular dependency and it should work

Comment: @Sherif: Unfortunately actual class Producer should be static class (or singleton at maximum). Logic in getMember() is actually quite complex and so it is not just a collection: hence a whole class. At the moment I think about making Producer to be a singleton with interface. This singleton then will be passed to Member constructor (constuctor expects an object with interface, not a Producer). This way Member will call Producer without any direct reference to it. But I was hoping for cleaner solution.

Comment: @Kazz: it works but it is circular dependency indeed: class Producer requires Member to work, class Member requires Producer to work. Without circular dependency one of them should be able to work without second one.